# Access - How to edit data in ether of two pop-up forms

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

Good afternoon,

I have two pop up forms in a database. The first form has contact information for our donors. The second form is spawned from the donors form by clicking a button to enter gift information for the donor (DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Gifts", , , , acFormAdd, , Me!C_ID), also a pop up. While both forms are visible to the user, only the data in the second form is editable. Users would like to be able to easily switch back and forth between forms without closing them.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Do not make the forms Modal. The Default is not modal so having two pop up forms open is just like having two windows open on your PC.

What have you already tried?

Comment: Evan, that worked. One form was modal, the other was not. As soon as I made that change, problem was solved. I'll admit that I didn't try much to solve it because I had no idea what would cause it. Searching for "edit two forms" or variations in Google always led to form design forum posts.I'm not a strong Access user, though work primarily in Excel and branching out to utilize Access as my data sets are getting too cumbersome to deal with in Excel. Too many calculated fields.

Comment: Understandable, Glad I could help and best of luck on your ventures into Access